# sqlalchemy polymorphism without discriminators

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, polymorphism, subtype

I am trying to use an external library which defines a class model in my own program. I want the classes I define to be the same in all respects to their parents from the library, except that I want to append some helper methods to my local extensions. For example:

**External Library:**

```
Base = declarative_base()
class BaseUser(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    email = Column(String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = Column(String(128), nullable=False)

    address_uid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('address.uid'))
    address = relationship('BaseAddress', back_populates="users")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.address = BaseAddress()

class BaseAddress(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'

    street = Column(String(100))
    unit = Column(String(32))
    city = Column(String(64))
    state = Column(String(32))
    postal = Column(String(32))
    country = Column(String(32))

    users = relationship('user', back_populates="address")
```

**Local model:**

```
class User(BaseUser):
    def in_country(county):
        return self.address.country == country

class Address(BaseAddress):
    pass
```

The goal here is to create subclasses which sqlalchemy need not distinguish from their parents. If I insert an `Address` into `User.address`, for example, sqlalchemy should not complain about a type mismatch (`Address` instead of the expected `BaseAddress`).

The only way of doing this that I can discern would involve using `polymorphic_on` in the parent classes. I don't want to do this, because it doesn't accurately model what is happening. It would require a discriminator, and it might behave strangely in the event I used a migration script locally. Is there a way with sqlalchemy to achieve polymorphism (I think it's called "ad-hoc polymorphism") *without* using discriminators, or some other way of achieving my goal?

**UPDATE**

I believe I could get part of the way there by using `enable_typechecks=False` on the relationships. However, this doesn't exactly get me what I want. I'd like to be able to do things like `User.query()` and get back a `User` rather than a `BaseUser`.

Comment: Why can't you just monkeypatch the methods you want to the classes in the library?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. When working with SA I guess I've kind of learned to try to avoid doing anything that isn't the "SA way" lest I experience unexpected behavior down the road. I'll give some monkeypatching a shot and see if it works out.

Comment: @univerio So, although monkeypatching did work, I'm not excited about it as a solution. The code is a lot harder to read than it would be with "normal" class definitions. I'm worried this solution isn't very maintainable. It works though, so big thanks for that.

Comment: You can make a decorator factory like `def apply_mixin(cls)` that patches all the attributes of the received class to `cls`, and return the base class instead. That way you're not straying too far from the `class User` syntax. Alternatively, depending on how the external library is set up, you can potentially *copy* its attributes to a new class that you define.